# October CMS Single page management

Tags: octobercms

I'm trying to build a single page web site by using october CMS.
October CMS has capability to create seperate pages with different urls.

But I want to create a single page web site, that able to manage content without knowing html&php.

This page will have 4-5 sections, all section has own design title and content. Each section will be displayed with paralax effects.

So, what is the best way to edit single page sections and content.

Answer (score 3):

you can use partial as section 
and also you can set different design set in each partial
and the menu url in set only id of the partial's parent tag.

Partials
 Partials contain reusable chunks of HTML markup.

Partials are chunks of HTML defined in separate files which can be included anywhere. Below code ins use to load partial in home page

```
{% partial "partial-name" %}
```

and you can create partials as shown in below image 
[image]

Refrence Link : [octobercms-partial-use](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/partials)

Answer (score 1):

This is now also possible, in a much more elegant fashion, by using the Static Pages plugin [here](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages) combined with [placeholder tags](http://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-placeholder)

A static page layout can now be created like:

```
<html>
  <body>

  {% if placeholder('home') %}
    <section id="home">
      {% placeholder home %}
    </section>
  {% endif %}

  {% if placeholder('section1') %}
    <section id="section1">
      {% placeholder section1 %}
    </section>
  {% endif %}

  </body>
</html>
```

And multiple tabs will be presented on the page editor to edit the relevant content.